# Can't remember a story about people having unique knacks

Tags: story-identification

There is a story where every one is shown to have a unique knack. For example, one man can make an ashtray-sized object vanish (but he can't bring it back). Another man's knack is to be able to transport a person/object between two cabinets. As far as I recall, this was a short story in some collection.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you remember if the setting was more fantasy or sci-fi? Or when you read it?

Comment: Hmm... more fantasy than sci-fi I'd say. Also, I must have read it atleast 15 years ago.

Comment: Hmm.. Each person having a Unique 'knack' makes me think of Pier Anthony's '[Xanth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanth)' books... But they were not short stories... Orson Scott Card's 'Alvin Maker' books had [a few short stories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvin_Maker#Short_works_in_the_series) connected to them, and specifically used the term 'knack'; either sound familiar?

Comment: @KeithHWeston Thanks for the answer. I've read both the series. This story was unrelated and just a short story, not a series.

Comment: It reminds me of the psi talents that people in Larry Niven's Long Arm of Gil Hamilton stories have, but I don't think it quite fits.

Comment: @Pixel I haven't read that one, but it sounds interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some story from Wild Cards universe?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Cards

Comment: Hmm. Close, but I remember this story as being stand-alone, not part of a universe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"A Trick or Two" by John Novotny features Jesse, a rather nasty man who discovers that his trick is transporting a person between cabinets. The person emerges sans clothing. He does this to Laura, a woman he's pursuing- only to find that she has a talent of her own.

Jesse's friend Tom can make small objects disappear; he demonstrates this with an ashtray.

I have this in the collection "A Decade of Fantasy and Science Fiction" (1964) edited by
Robert P. Mills.

Comment: You got it! Thanks!

Comment: You're quite welcome. One of my favorite SF books.

Comment: That's the one I was looking for :)