# Identify a short story involving a blond that makes a fire poker sag

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I found a box of books in the attic of a new house at age 12, the summer of 1963.  It contained 2 sf anthologies.  One was Damon Knight stories.

The other one was a hard bound collection of multiple stories by multiple authors with many different themes.  The  (not Damon Knight) story I recently remembered involved a pathetic guy (with blond roots) who has been trying to seduce a beautiful non-stereotypical blond.  She demonstrates, in the last paragraph, a "trick"  that causes a fire poker to suddenly sag.

I didn't get at age 12, but when something reminded me of the scene a while back I did and started laughing out loud.

It probably would have been funniest when I was a high school sophomore, but I would like to see if I can locate the story and maybe even the anthology.

Ah, retirement.  I think the  was yellow.

Comment: *"I think the was yellow."* The what was yellow?

Comment: I'm guessing cover.

Comment: As soon as I read this, I realized that I had read this at some point and didn't remember the answer either. Thanks for asking.

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/cant-remember-a-story-about-people-having-unique-knacks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's ["A Trick or Two"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74322), a short story by [John Novotny](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?14938); first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, July 1957](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61164), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v013n01_1957-07_AK/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v013n01_1957-07_AK#page/n47/mode/2up). The ending:

> Jesse walked wonderingly to the fireplace, picked up the poker, and held it out. Laura raised a long slender forefinger and pointed at the brass tool; and in Jesse's hand the poker became pliable, soft, and wilted like wax before a flame. He stared at it in horror.
>
> "Jesse," Laura said, "I discovered my trick long ago."

**The anthology** was probably [*A Decade of Fantasy and Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?36296) ([Robert P. Mills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_P._Mills), ed.); maybe the [contents](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?459) or [cover](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?36296) will ring a bell.

**The Damon Knight collection,** if it was published before 1963, was probably his 1961 collection [*Far Out*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?260394); his second collection, [*In Deep*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?17957), published in May of 1963; seems less likely to be found in a box in an attic in the summer of 1963.

Comment: i probably would have asked this at some point. Good to know.

Comment: Fastest gun in the west!